# Space Invaders in Java... Components or paint

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm experienced in Java and I've done a little with Swing (form type apps), but I've never needed more power than that so I don't know much about what's going on under the hood GUI-wise. Here is what I've gleaned from the little bit of reading I've been doing. I'm sure it's off.

In writing a space invaders type game, two approaches I thought of would be:

1. Create one big component and code for all the incremental painting and layering.
2. Create a bunch of nested absolutely positioned JPanels in a JLayeredPane that contains text and images, then call repaint() on just the ones that might need to be redrawn. Then override paintComponent() (not sure if previous content is cleared automatically or not). From what I read, this would handle the layering and redrawing of components without having to redraw the whole screen.

Is this correct? If so, which method is better suited for the project?

Comment: @Charles Thanks! Sorry about that. I really do value the help I've gotten here. I need to be diligent and say so!

Comment: See also [*Space Invaders 101*](http://www.stumbleupon.com/su/8wGoxm/www.cokeandcode.com/info/tut2d.html).

Comment: I'd suggest to look away from Swing altogether, as you have rightly pointed out yourself - it's for GUI, not games. Do a bit of a research into game specific Java libraries available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to really consider when it comes down to game programming in Java is to switch to Active Rendering.

as we know, Swing takes care of rendering in another thread, called Event Dispatch Thread. This is known as passive rendering, because you don't really render your own visual components, but you define how your app will look like and Swing actually draws it when he wants.

Games usually work in Full Screen mode and often require more control over the "when", "how" and "what" will be drawn. This is called active rendering. In this case, you have to disable the Even Dispatch Thread and do the rendering on your own.

It all makes sense, because games often work inside a big loop. One example of a game loop is:

1. Get input data (keyboard, joystick, etc)
2. Network communication (in case of a client-server game)
3. Process logic according to input data. (Eventually, this will lead to the game exiting, when the user tells it to).
4. Update the state machine of the game.
5. Redraw the scene according to the new state
6. Restart the loop.

There are many sources, but I can suggest this first reading to clarify on that: [Passive vs Active Rendering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/rendering.html)

Comment: Another more complete resource: http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/java-games-active-rendering-r2418

Comment: Very interesting... It seems that the app won't necessarily play nice w/ window resizes etc. though, right? What if you put all your rendering code in one top level component, then had a loop that called repaint() over and over? Could you get the windowing events and have more control?

Comment: In fact, when you activate the Full Screen mode, you set the window to one of the sizes supported by the Operating System/Graphics Card. This way, the window actually occupies the whole screen. If you need to resize it, it is actually done as it is on any game: you programatically set the active dimension to be one of the supported Display Modes. java.awt.DisplayMode is a set of width, height, bitDepth and refresh rate.

Comment: May I suggest you to check the Java Full Screen mode example in http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt/screen_FullWin.html and other features in the subsection "Related Examples"? Among the other features is an example of how to obtain the available Display Modes.

Comment: In a game, usually, after obtaining a list of all installed Graphic Devices and their respective Display Modes, you present the User the option to chose from one of them. Many games come to my memory right now: I choose an "video options" dialog, then I am presented a definite set of resolutions and then I chose one. When I press "Activate", the game engine switches to it.

Answer (score 2):

**Some thoughts on your approaches**

The first approach will probably perform better, because you could just use a single VolatileImage for the whole drawing.  However, you're right about it being more complicated than the second approach, because you will have to handle all the layering yourself.

The second approach is nice not just for the reasons you've state, but because if you need to do anything like handle when a mouse enters a specific "sprite" on the screen, that is given to you automatically by Java's JPanel implementation.  That said...  Space Invaders clones are typically controlled by the keyboard, so whether or not you actually use this functionality is another story entirely.

Bottom line...  I usually end up doing this kind of stuff in the `paint()` paradigm.  Layering the paint is not that hard at all, especially for something as simple as Space Invaders, and it will make improving performance easier if you decide to use `VolatileImage` as your back buffer.

**Other thoughts**

As others have said, it's tough to get consistent "frame rates" in swing because you have no control over "when" something gets rendered - that is determined by the EDT, which runs asynchronously with respect to your code.  If you decide to rely on the EDT, you might try using a `SwingTimer` for your rendering.  Be extra careful to synchronize your rendering and updates to the underlying game state properly as well.